# $_FILE does not get file and lead to undefined variable PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get an image file sent from html form in order to insert it in a database. It's unfortunately not working because the file is not posted.

All the other variables are working, I echoed them to check, but the file isn't. Where is my problem? I think it's at the html form, the inserted variables are also in the same form but in different divisions, so the post actually send all data in the form to post.php but not the image file.

As you can see I already include "enctype="multipart/form-data"".

Any help please?

1) HTML markup:

```
 <form action="post.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="hidden" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000"/>
    <div>
        <input type="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect[]" multiple accept="image/*"/>
        <div id="filedrag">or drop files here</div>
    </div>

    <div id="submitbutton">
        <button type="submit">Upload Files</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

2) PHP code:

```
$title=isset($_POST['title'])?$_POST['title']:false;
$desc=isset($_POST['description'])?$_POST['description']:false;
$date=date("Y-M-D");
$city=isset($_POST['city'])?$_POST['city']:false;
$user=isset($_POST['name'])?$_POST['name']:false;
$price=isset($_POST['price'])?$_POST['price']:false;
$table=isset($_POST['option'])?$_POST['option']:false;
$imgfile=isset($_FILE['file']['name'])?$_FILE['fileselect']['name']:false;
$tmp_dir=isset($_FILE['fileselect']['tmp_name'])?$_FILE['fileselect'['tmp_name']:false;

$img_size=isset($_FILE['fileselect']['size'])?$_FILE['fileselect']['size']:false;
$upload_dir='images/'; // directory
     $imgExt=strtolower(pathinfo($imgfile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // GET IMAGE EXTENSION

     $valid_ext=array('jpeg','jpg','png','gif');

     //rename uploading image

     $item_img=rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;
     // allow valid image format

     if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_ext))
     {
         if($img_size < 500000)
         {
             move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$item_img);
         }
         else{
             $erMsg="Sorry , your file is too large";
         }
     }
     else{
         $erMsg="Sorry,only JPG,JPEG,PNG & GIF files are accepted :)";
     }


$query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO '.$table .'(title,description,image,date,city,user,price) VALUES(:title, :description, :image, :date, :city, :user, :price)');

$query->bindParam(':title', $title);
$query->bindParam(':description', $desc);
$query->bindParam(':image', $item_img);
$query->bindParam(':date', $date);
$query->bindParam(':city', $city);
$query->bindParam(':user', $user);
$query->bindParam(':price', $price);
```

Comment: Use enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: use `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to send files from your form it should have correct `enctype` attribute.

```
<form action="script.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: according to rules of this site answers should be posted as answers, not comments!

Comment: i have edited to add the "enctype" because it was included but wasn't still working . my bad , still not working

Comment: @JeanOuédraogo Maybe you have typo in array name? 
it should be `$_FILES` (multiple form) and you have `$_FILE` in your code

Comment: yeah works now , that was the mistake , thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you are working with file such as images, use the `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Answer (score 0):

Did you see you have a typo at the line ?

```
$tmp_dir=isset($_FILE['fileselect'['tmp_name'])$_FILE['fileselect'['tmp_name']:false;
```

you are missing `]` after `fileselect`'

Check that!!

Comment: yes that one is done thanks